# How do I round up the output of a formula in Excel 2016?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a formula in Excel:

```
=(1+E20+F20+G20)/4
```

The output is `3.25`. I want 3.25 to be rounded up to 4. How do I do that in the same cell? The `ROUNDUP` function seems to only be used when referencing other cells, not the output of the formula in the same cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`=ROUNDUP((SUM(1,E20,F20,G20))/4,0)`